# Motherboard fans not reporting speed

Tags: motherboard, fan

I have a Gigabyte GA-X99-Designare motherboard, and it's not reporting fan speeds to the OS.  I've tried SpeedFan and HWMonitor (Windows 10), and HWSensors and iStat Menus (OS X).  Same results in both operating systems:  One out of four fans shows speed accurately, and the others show 0rpm.  I can see that fans are definitely spinning and the all show correct speed in the BIOS.

It might be a coincidence, but the one fan that reports correctly is 3-pin, and the others are 4-pin PWM.

Comment: Have you installed the motherbaord drivers? I was under the impression that Windows 10 was good at doing that itself, but an explicit install might persuade it to behave correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of boards/chipsets don't work with 3rd party monitoring software for viewing temperatures and fan speeds.  Use the [utilities from Gigabyte for your motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5812#utility); specifically System Information Viewer, as it should provide you all that information, plus the ability to set fan speeds based on temperature, etc.

[image]

Comment: I guess you're right.  Gigabyte's SIV app does show the fan speeds.  I never heard of this happening, I thought fan speed was a fairly standard protocol between all motherboards.  I wonder if there's any way to get this working in OS X using DSDT edits.